# how to stop Vpython from being unresponsive

Tags: button, simulation, vpython

Im fairly new to Vpython and Ive created a simulation for circular motion. I tried adding controls to the simulation and so far I am able to pause the simulation but when i do pause it, the entire control panel becomes unresponsive and i am unable to resume the simulation. Does anyone know why this may be or how i can fix this?

```
 def playorpause(self, goorno):
    self.pause = goorno

def actual_sim(self):

    c = controls()  # Create controls window
    # Create a button in the controls window:

    # b = Button(pos=(-50, 0), width=60, height=60, text="Pause", action=lambda: self.change)
    # play = Button(pos=(50, 0), width=60, height=60, text="Play", command = self.play_sim)

    b = button(pos=(-50, 0), width=60, height=60, text='Pause', action=lambda: self.playorpause(True))
    play = button(pos=(50,0), width = 60, height = 60, text = "play", action =lambda: self.playorpause(False))

  def loop():
#### simulation code
        if self.pause == False:
            loop()
```

Comment: When you pause the program, it actually exits, as the 'loop' is exited.

Comment: @m00lti , Okay, could you advise me on how to stop that from happening. How would i make it pause without exiting the loop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, because I don't really understand your code, but a repetitive loop needs to include a rate statement. Otherwise the program will lock up, unable to output anything.